# How to change an array if it is const?

Tags: c, tcp, constants, binaryfiles

This program reads and writes on a binary file. The professor is asking to switch the value of the source port and destination port. But I know we can not change if it is const, I also get this error. Does anyone know what he means by that or have any idea how I can switch? Thanks a lot.

```
error: assignment of read-only location ‘*array’

/*array = the array the data is stored.*/
void header(const unsigned char array [], unsigned char filename [])
{
   
}
```

Comment: I think we're going to need some more details.

Comment: You can cast the `const` away so that the compiler accepts the line ... and possibly suffer the consequences at runtime: `((unsigned char *)array)[0] = 42;`

Comment: A function with that format cannot swap the contents of `array`, period. Why do you have a function that's supposed to swap data around named `header` and passed on a `filename` parameter? None of your naming makes any sense. Is this the right function to begin with?

Comment: How about revise the program so that `array` isn't const. Is that an option? Casting away const is possible, but it's an escape hatch and better to avoid having to do so in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through pointers:

```
void header(const unsigned char array [], unsigned char filename [])
{
    char *array2 = (char *)array;
    // You can freely modify array2 elements here, resulting in the original array's modification   
}
```

Comment: `header("foobar", "foo.txt"); // BOOOOMM`